# bash profile is not loaded while running a remote script with ssh

Tags: bash, docker, shell, ssh, alpine-linux

**Situation:**

There is a bash script called `hello.sh` on `HOST-A`. This script uses some environment variables that are available on `HOST-A`. I am executing this script from `HOST-B`.

When I execute the  `hello.sh` locally from `HOST-A` it sees the environment variables.
But if I run the script from `HOST-B` using ssh, the script does not see the environment variables.

**Environment:**

- `HOST-A` and `HOST-B` are docker containers based on `alpine:3.17.3`.

- Port `13012` is the docker port of `HOST-A` (`13012:22`)
- Port `13022` is the docker port of `HOST-B` (`13022:22`)

**Test, that works like a charm:**

- When I log in to `HOST-A` using docker `exec -it HOST-A /bin/bash` then the script sees the environment variables.
- When I log in to `HOST-A` using `ssh -p 13012 root@localhost` then the script sees the environment variables. Port `13012` is the SSH port of the `HOST-A` that Docker maps to the host machine.
- When I log in to `HOST-B`, then `ssh HOST-A`, then run the script, the script sees the environment variables. Here I test the ssh connection between the hosts in Docker too.

**Issue:**

The bash profile is not set when I run the script remotely from `HOST-B` using the

```
[root@HOST-B]# sshpass -p "password" \
                  ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no root@HOST-A 'bash -s < /hello.sh param'
```

When I try to run the script from the docker host machine using `sshpass -p "password" ssh -p 13012 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "root@localhost" 'bash -s < /hello.sh param'` then it also does not work, the bash profile is not set.

**Warning:**
The `param` must be a variable: `$param`

I think that the issue is that the bash profile is not set when I connect with ssh.

**What I have tried but did not work:**

I created `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`. They have exactly the same content:

```
# pwd
/root

# ls -all
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            86 May 14 23:52 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            86 May 14 22:38 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            86 May 14 22:52 .profile
```

How to set bash profile properly for ssh remote execution in `alpine` Linux?

☆☆☆ UPDATE ☆☆☆

If I `source` the `.bashrc` in the `hello.sh` then everything works fine. But this is a hack, looks really bad.

source ~/.bashrc

Comment: bash rc files are intended to be used in interactive shells. `source ~/.bashrc` is the correct way. it's not a hack.

Comment: I disagree. I think that this is a `hack` / not a good solution. For example, if I add a new user then this solution will not work with this new user. And I have never seen this kind of source. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: If you want the .bash_profile of the remote host's home directory be sourced, you have to create a login shell, i.e. `bash -l`.  See the section _INVOCATION_ in the bash man page.

Comment: bash rc files are intended to be used in interactive shells -- this is why bash by default would not load these rc files for non-interactive shells. for non-interactive use i'd suggest you put your common files in a specific dir and load them explicitly.

Comment: some bash features are only available for interactive shells. some need to be explicitly enabled (e.g. aliases support) if want to use in scripts. it's not quite common to share the same rc files for interactive and non-interactive shells.

Comment: @user1934428 If you post it as a solution then I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have .bash_profile being processed, you need to specify the `-l` option when invoking *bash*. This makes bash a login shell. In this case, the other login-startup-files are processed too (as specified in the section *INVOCATION* of the bash man-page), for instance `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Thx for your help finally I was able to create the right command: `sshpass -p "$SSH_PASSWORD" ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$SSH_USER@$HELLO_HOST" "bash -lc '/hello.sh $param'"`